# What are needed when running an elf like running dalvikvm on debian?

Tags: android, c++, linux, linker, android-x86

I wanna run dalvikvm on my debian just for try.

1. I installed android x86 and copied all /system/ files to my debian
2. make ln -s /system/ /system/system
3. readelf -d dalvikvm and ldd to make sure the dependencies are okay
4. make sure linker is ok (/system/bin/linker)
5. chroot /system /system/bin/sh
6. run dalvikvm -h or dalvikvm -showversion and everything seems okay
7. run dalvikvm returns "Aborted"
8. run dalvikvm to launch dex, returns "Aborted"

**My questions is when firing a executable program, when**

1. instruction set is okay (x86)
2. linker is okay ( /system/bin/linker )
3. dependencies are all okay, ( see the picture below )

Why it could not run right? what did I miss?

[image]

Comment: I'm going to skip closing this, because I think it can be improved with more information about the specific 'edge' of the problem that you've discovered.  Right now, it's way too vague.